# go lang installation error - raspberrypi

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumjs, golang, geth-debugging, raspberry-pi

I needed to create privatenet in raspberrypi and installed go1.9. Cloned geth, extracted it. When 'make geth' command is passed I get following error. Please help me out

```
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3
# github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/dashboard
fatal error: runtime: out of memory

runtime stack:
# github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-
duktape.v3
In file included from vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-
duktape.v3/api.go:7:0:
vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3/api.go: In function 
‘_duk_error’:
vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3/duktape.h:510:127: warning: 
right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
(duk_error_raw((ctx), (duk_errcode_t) (err_code), (const char *) 
(DUK_FILE_MACRO), (duk_int_t) (DUK_LINE_MACRO), __VA_ARGS__), 
(duk_ret_t) 0)


vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3/api.go:153:2: note: in 
expansion of macro ‘duk_error’
duk_error(ctx, err_code, "%s", str);

# github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-
duktape.v3
vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3/duktape.go:119: cannot use fn 
(type func(*Context) int) as type func(*Context) uint in argument to 
d.PushGoFunction
vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3/duktape.go:129: cannot use fn 
(type func(*Context) uint) as type func(*Context) int in argument to 
d.context.fnIndex.add
vendor/gopkg.in/olebedev/go-duktape.v3/duktape.go:132: constant 
18446744073709551615 overflows int64
util.go:45: exit status 2
exit status 1
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'geth' failed
make: *** [geth] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix is documented in the [source repository on github](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15752#issuecomment-354253999). As suggested, upgrading go to 1.9.2 fixed the issue for me.